# DevExpress ASP.NET - Want to use Razor without MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress

I test the DevExpress (DX) ASP.NET

I want to make website with DX and Razor view.
When I create a new Web Project. I can choose between :

1. DXperience v12.2 ASP.NET Web Application
2. DXperience v12.2 ASP.NET MVC Web Application

In the choice 1, I can't choose the view language, Visual Studio create an ASPX website.
If I choose MVC, in the creation wizard, I can choose Razor or ASPX.

My question is can I create a website using Razor view without the MVC ?
I don't know the MVC pattern and be affraid to learn it now, I don't understand the logic inside it...

Comment: [Here's a guide I found to do it](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=208). But it's well worth learning MVC, on the surface it does appear to be a lot of magic, but once you're familiar with it, it starts make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks for link. I know that I can make website in Razor withour MVC; like a basic PHP website. I want to know if the DevExpress ASP.NET controls are usable without having to create a `DXperience v12.2 ASP.NET MVC Web Application`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are specifically looking to do, you should check out [RazorEngine](https://razorengine.codeplex.com) - it lets you render HTML from Razor without alot of the scaffolding that you will have to do in order to use Razor like MVC uses Razor...